# Css background image for li

Tags: css

I have the following

.toggle_container .block ul {
    margin: 0 0 7px 0;
}

.toggle_container .block li {
    list-style-type:none;
    color: #232120;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height:1.2em;
    padding: 4px 0px 2px 23px;

```
background:  url(images/red-bullet.gif)no-repeat; 
background-position: 3% 45%;
```

}

The trouble is the image moves downwards if I have more than one line of text in the

tag

Thanks<

Answer (score 1):

Where you have:

`background-position: 3% 45%;`

Try using px values instead of percentages. So change the 3% and 45% to the offset of the image you want, something like 3px 45px.

You could also replace 3% and 45% with 'top left' to fix the position to the top left..

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as correct if it was. Click the tick that is to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well Isnt that typical. Done a bit more searching and found the answer, so thought I would answer my own question.

I mixed position percentages and pixels as follows:
background-position: 3% 9px;